# How to use JavaScript's sql-formatter library to parse a SQL statement that contains the nested concat function in the where condition

Tags: javascript, sql, regular-language

I want to implement a formatted SQL function on the front end. Among them, SQL may contain some mybatis-specific syntax, such as '#{var}'.
The input is SQL compressed into one line; the output is formatted SQL.
The figure below is an example of input and output:
[figure of input and output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqayq.png)
input example:

```
select distinct a.name_order as "nameorder", #{authId}  as "authid", trim(authType) as "authType", concat('org-', a.org_icon) as "iconCls" from table_user a left join (select b.obj_type, b.obj_id from table_object a left join table_auth_data b on a.auth_id = b.id where a.auth = aa) b on (b.obj_type = trim(a.auth_type) and b.object_id = aa)  where a.parent is null and trim(c.org_id) = #{org_Id} order by a.order asc
```

However, when I add the nested concat() function to the where part of the SQL statement, the parsing will fail, such as:

errer 1:
input

```
select distinct a.name_order as "nameorder", #{authId}  as "authid", trim(authType) as "authType", concat('org-', a.org_icon) as "iconCls" from table_user a left join (select b.obj_type, b.obj_id from table_object a left join table_auth_data b on a.auth_id = b.id where a.auth = concat('a', concat('b', 'c'))) b on (b.obj_type = trim(a.auth_type) and b.object_id = aa)  where a.parent is null and trim(c.org_id) = #{org_Id} order by a.order asc
```

The error message is very long:

```
nearley.js:343 Uncaught Error: Parse error at token: ) at line 1 column 309
Unexpected CLOSE_PAREN token: {"type":"CLOSE_PAREN","raw":")","text":")","start":308}. Instead, I was expecting to see one of the following:

A PROPERTY_ACCESS_OPERATOR token based on:
    property_access → atomic_expression _ ● %PROPERTY_ACCESS_OPERATOR _ property_access$subexpression$1
    atomic_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● property_access
    atomic_expression →  ● atomic_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● atomic_expression
    asteriskless_andless_expression →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression
    asteriskless_free_form_sql →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql
    free_form_sql →  ● free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    other_clause$ebnf$1 → other_clause$ebnf$1 ● free_form_sql
    other_clause → %RESERVED_CLAUSE ● other_clause$ebnf$1
    clause$subexpression$1 →  ● other_clause
    clause →  ● clause$subexpression$1
    expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 ● clause
    expressions_or_clauses → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$1 ● expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2
    statement →  ● expressions_or_clauses statement$subexpression$1
    main$ebnf$1 → main$ebnf$1 ● statement
    main →  ● main$ebnf$1
A LINE_COMMENT token based on:
    comment →  ● %LINE_COMMENT
    _$ebnf$1 → _$ebnf$1 ● comment
    _ →  ● _$ebnf$1
    property_access → atomic_expression ● _ %PROPERTY_ACCESS_OPERATOR _ property_access$subexpression$1
......Due to character limit, some error messages are omitted here.
A RESERVED_JOIN token based on:
    keyword$subexpression$1 →  ● %RESERVED_JOIN
    keyword →  ● keyword$subexpression$1
    atomic_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● keyword
    atomic_expression →  ● atomic_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● atomic_expression
    asteriskless_andless_expression →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression
    asteriskless_free_form_sql →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql
    free_form_sql →  ● free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    other_clause$ebnf$1 → other_clause$ebnf$1 ● free_form_sql
    other_clause → %RESERVED_CLAUSE ● other_clause$ebnf$1
    clause$subexpression$1 →  ● other_clause
    clause →  ● clause$subexpression$1
    expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 ● clause
    expressions_or_clauses → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$1 ● expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2
    statement →  ● expressions_or_clauses statement$subexpression$1
    main$ebnf$1 → main$ebnf$1 ● statement
    main →  ● main$ebnf$1

    at T.O.feed (nearley.js:343:27)
    at Object.parse (createParser.ts:33:34)
    at CA.parse (Formatter.ts:37:49)
    at CA.format (Formatter.ts:31:22)
    at tA (sqlFormatter.ts:96:57)
    at Module.sA (sqlFormatter.ts:69:10)
    at formatSQL (mybatis-xml - 副本.html:68:33)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (mybatis-xml - 副本.html:62:30)
```

============================================
error 2:
input

```
select distinct a.name_order as "nameorder", #{authId}  as "authid", trim(authType) as "authType", concat('org-', a.org_icon) as "iconCls" from table_user a left join (select b.obj_type, b.obj_id from table_object a left join table_auth_data b on a.auth_id = b.id where a.auth = concat(trim(a), concat('b', 'c'))) b on (b.obj_type = trim(a.auth_type) and b.object_id = aa)  where a.parent is null and trim(c.org_id) = #{org_Id} order by a.order asc
```

The error message:

```
nearley.js:343 Uncaught Error: Parse error at token: ) at line 1 column 313
Unexpected CLOSE_PAREN token: {"type":"CLOSE_PAREN","raw":")","text":")","start":312}. Instead, I was expecting to see one of the following:

A PROPERTY_ACCESS_OPERATOR token based on:
    property_access → atomic_expression _ ● %PROPERTY_ACCESS_OPERATOR _ property_access$subexpression$1
    atomic_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● property_access
    atomic_expression →  ● atomic_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● atomic_expression
    asteriskless_andless_expression →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression
    asteriskless_free_form_sql →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql
    free_form_sql →  ● free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    other_clause$ebnf$1 → other_clause$ebnf$1 ● free_form_sql
    other_clause → %RESERVED_CLAUSE ● other_clause$ebnf$1
    clause$subexpression$1 →  ● other_clause
    clause →  ● clause$subexpression$1
    expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 ● clause
    expressions_or_clauses → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$1 ● expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2
    statement →  ● expressions_or_clauses statement$subexpression$1
    main$ebnf$1 → main$ebnf$1 ● statement
    main →  ● main$ebnf$1
A LINE_COMMENT token based on:
    comment →  ● %LINE_COMMENT
    _$ebnf$1 → _$ebnf$1 ● comment
    _ →  ● _$ebnf$1
    property_access → atomic_expression ● _ %PROPERTY_ACCESS_OPERATOR _ property_access$subexpression$1
    atomic_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● property_access
    atomic_expression →  ● atomic_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1 →  ● atomic_expression
    asteriskless_andless_expression →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression$subexpression$1
    asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_andless_expression
    asteriskless_free_form_sql →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    free_form_sql$subexpression$1 →  ● asteriskless_free_form_sql
    free_form_sql →  ● free_form_sql$subexpression$1
    other_clause$ebnf$1 → other_clause$ebnf$1 ● free_form_sql
    other_clause → %RESERVED_CLAUSE ● other_clause$ebnf$1
    clause$subexpression$1 →  ● other_clause
    clause →  ● clause$subexpression$1
    expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2 ● clause
    expressions_or_clauses → expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$1 ● expressions_or_clauses$ebnf$2
    statement →  ● expressions_or_clauses statement$subexpression$1
    main$ebnf$1 → main$ebnf$1 ● statement
    main →  ● main$ebnf$1
......Due to character limit, some error messages are omitted here.

    at T.O.feed (nearley.js:343:27)
    at Object.parse (createParser.ts:33:34)
    at CA.parse (Formatter.ts:37:49)
    at CA.format (Formatter.ts:31:22)
    at tA (sqlFormatter.ts:96:57)
    at Module.sA (sqlFormatter.ts:69:10)
    at formatSQL (mybatis-xml - 副本.html:68:33)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (mybatis-xml - 副本.html:62:30)
T.O.feed @ nearley.js:343
parse @ createParser.ts:33
parse @ Formatter.ts:37
format @ Formatter.ts:31
tA @ sqlFormatter.ts:96
sA @ sqlFormatter.ts:69
formatSQL @ mybatis-xml - 副本.html:68
```

===========================================================

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SQL parse</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .xml-container {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 75%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .xml-container pre {
            font-size: 18px;
            min-height: 40px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc; 
            padding: 10px; 
            overflow-y: auto; 
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="xml-container">
            <pre id="originalXml" contenteditable></pre>
        </div>
        <button id="parseButton">parse SQL</button>
        <div class="xml-container">
            <h3>parsed data</h3>
            <pre id="parsedData" style="font-size: 18px;"></pre>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sql-formatter/dist/sql-formatter.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var parseButton = document.getElementById("parseButton");

        var originalXmlPre = document.getElementById("originalXml");

        var loopParsedDataPre = document.getElementById("parsedData");

        parseButton.addEventListener("click", function () {

            var xmlString = originalXmlPre.textContent;
            var parsedData = formatSQL(xmlString);
            loopParsedDataPre.textContent = parsedData;

        });

        function formatSQL(sql) {
            return sqlFormatter.format(sql, {
                language: 'sql',
                paramTypes: {
                    custom: [
                        { regex: String.raw`#\{(.+?)\}`},

                        { regex: String.raw`trim\(.+?\)`, flags: 'i'},
                        
                        { regex: String.raw`concat\(.+?\)`, flags: 'i'}, 

                        { regex: String.raw`concat(.+?)`, flags: 'i'}, 

                        { regex: String.raw`concat.+?concat.+?\)\)`, flags: 'i'}, 

                        { regex: String.raw`concat(.+?)concat(.+?)`, flags: 'i'}, 
                        
                    ],
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

my attempt：

I tried to use the custom regular function of sqlFormatter to solve the problem, but at best it could only solve a simple concat(). It completely failed for nested concat() and concat() containing trim().
Regular definition code：

```
function formatSQL(sql) {
            return sqlFormatter.format(sql, {
                language: 'sql',
                paramTypes: {
                    custom: [
                        { regex: String.raw`#\{(.+?)\}`},

                        { regex: String.raw`trim\(.+?\)`, flags: 'i'},
                        
                        { regex: String.raw`concat\(.+?\)`, flags: 'i'}, 

                        { regex: String.raw`concat(.+?)`, flags: 'i'}, 

                        { regex: String.raw`concat.+?concat.+?\)\)`, flags: 'i'}, 

                        { regex: String.raw`concat(.+?)concat(.+?)`, flags: 'i'}, 
                        
                    ],
                },
            });
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be enough: `custom: [{ regex: String.raw`#\{(.+?)\}`}],` and it looks like you can remove all of the other regexes. This passes for all three of your test cases, and there are no errors. Is this output good enough, or did you expect something along the lines of breaking a nested `concat` into multiple lines? **EDIT** Stackoverflow's markup breaks the formatting. Just keep the first regex in your original code, and remove the rest.

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart for your help. Your suggestions successfully helped me solve the problem. The program no longer reported errors and I got the output I wanted. My question seems a bit idiotic, I can't remember what problem I originally added those redundant regular expression rules to solve. @FiddlingAway

Comment: Glad I could help. Everyone runs into a dead-end every now and then, it's perfectly normal. Also, if I may suggest something - answer your own question with an explanation on how you resolved the issue. Although it's specific to your own case, perhaps someone else will run into the same (or similar) problem, and your potential answer would help them resolve this problem. As it is now - the solution is in the comments, and not as noticeable as an answer would be.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the comment area, I have solved the problem. Only need to keep the first regular rule `` regex: String.raw`#\{(.+?)\}` `` and delete the remaining regular rules.

Additionally, I posted the code on GitHub. If your need is to format SQL statements with mybatis XML labels on the front end, then this repository may be able to help you: [https://github.com/hikari-He/format-SQL-with-Mybatis-label/blob /main/readme-EN.md](https://github.com/hikari-He/format-SQL-with-Mybatis-label/blob/main/readme-EN.md)